# how to make user choose different color pattern in php

Tags: php, html, colors

```
<form action="" method="post" id="customer-register">
<table align="center">
 <div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to Registration Page!</h1>

       <td>Full Name:</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="enter your name">
</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>Username:</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="enter your 
username"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>Email:</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter your email">
</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>Select your Password:</td>
       <td><input type="color" name="color1" value="#ff0000"><input 
type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000"><input type="color" name="color3" 
value="#ff0000"><input type="color" name="color4" value="#ff0000"><input 
type="color" name="color5" value="#ff0000"></td>
    </tr>
       <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
 </tr>    
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code for my register.php project. As you can see, I am not using text password, instead im allowing user to pick 5 type of colour to register.My question is there a source code for me to make sure that user do not enter the same color pattern as other user which have entered and saved in the database?

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
   $uname=$_POST['uname'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $pass1=$_POST['color1'];
   $pass2=$_POST['color2'];
   $pass3=$_POST['color3'];
   $pass4=$_POST['color4'];
   $pass5=$_POST['color5'];
   $register_query = "INSERT INTO `cust`(`fname`, `uname`, `email`, 
`color1`, `color2`, `color3`, `color4`, `colo5`) VALUES 
('$fname','$uname','$email','$pass1', '$pass2', '$pass3', '$pass4', 
'$pass5')";
   try{
       $register_result = mysqli_query($conn,$register_query);
       if($register_result){
           if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){
               header("location: success.html");
           }else{
               echo("error in registeration");
           }


       }

    }catch(Exception $ex){
       echo("error" .$ex->getMessage());
    }
 }else {

 }
   this is my code for handling the register.
```

Comment: why don't check if color is already in the user table?

Comment: @FastSnail the color is already in the user table and user are able to register. But the problem is if other user entering the same color as the previous user did, it still save it in the user table.How do i make sure that all user do not have the same color pattern during the register?Is there a code for validating it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do a query before the INSERT query.

```
$check_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `cust` WHERE `color1`='$pass1' AND `color2`='$pass2' AND `color3`='$pass3' AND `color4`='$pass4' AND `color5`='$pass5'";
if ($check_res = mysqli_query($conn, $check_query)) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_res);
    if ($row['total'] > 0) {
        // this means you shouldn't do the insert as a customer exists with this exact sequence of colours.
    }
    else {
        // do your insert here.
    }
}
```

If the value of `total` is > 0, then you know there is a customer with those exact colour combinations. This assumes a specific order of colours.